# Problem with JPA Update query when using @SecondaryTable and @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing a new feature on an existing app that have two tables set up like this :

```
table MESSAGE
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+----------------------------------+-------+
| Field                       | Type          | Null | Key | Default                          | Extra |
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+----------------------------------+-------+
| CAMPAIGN_NAME               | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| CAMPAIGN_UUID_FK            | char(36)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                             |       |
| TITRE                       | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| DESTINATION                 | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| DESTINATAIRES_AS_STRING     | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| TEXT                        | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| TYPE                        | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| FROM_FIELD                  | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| SENT_DATE                   | datetime      | NO   | PRI | 2005-01-01 00:00:00              |       |
| COST                        | decimal(12,4) | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| CREATION_DATE               | datetime      | NO   |     | 2005-01-01 00:00:00              |       |
| REFERENCE                   | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| COMPTE_RENDU                | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| ACCOUNT_ID_FK               | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0                                |       |
| CLASS_TYPE                  | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL |                                  |       |
| MESSAGE_ID                  | char(36)      | NO   | PRI |                                  |       |
| MESSAGE_REPORT_REFERENCE_FK | varchar(12)   | YES  |     | NULL                             |       |
| MODEL_MESSAGE               | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | 0                                |       |
| DELETED                     | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | 0                                |       |
| INCOMING_MESSAGE            | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | 0                                |       |
| ACCESS_CHANNEL              | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0                                |       |
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+----------------------------------+-------+
```

and

```
table MESSAGE_REPORT
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| REPORT_REFERENCE     | char(36)     | NO   | PRI |                     |       |
| SENT_DATE            | datetime     | NO   |     | 2004-04-04 00:00:00 |       |
| STATUS               | varchar(20)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| CREATION_DATE        | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL                |       |
| SIZE                 | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| CALLBACK_URL         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| CALLBACK_URL_REPONSE | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| REF_CLIENT           | varchar(25)  | YES  | MUL | NULL                |       |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

And here is what their respective JPA Entities look like :

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "MESSAGE")
@SecondaryTable(
        name = "MESSAGE_REPORT",
        pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(
                name = "REPORT_REFERENCE"))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
        name="CLASS_TYPE",
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,
        length = 50)
public class Message extends AbstractMessageEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "CAMPAIGN_NAME", length = 50)
    protected String campaignName;

    @Column(name = "TITRE")
    protected String titre;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "DESTINATION")
    protected String destination;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "DESTINATAIRES_AS_STRING")
    protected String destinataireAsString;

    @Column(name = "REFERENCE", length = 100)
    protected String reference;

    @Column(name = "COMPTE_RENDU")
    protected Boolean compteRendu = Boolean.TRUE;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ID", length = 36)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    protected String messageId;

    @Column(name = "INCOMING_MESSAGE")
    protected Boolean incomingMessage = Boolean.FALSE;

    @Column(name = "DELETED")
    protected Boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;

    /**
     * relationship
     */

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID_FK")
    protected Channel channel;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAMPAIGN_UUID_FK")
    protected Campaign campaign;

    @Column(table = "MESSAGE_REPORT", name = "STATUS")
    protected String status;

    @Column(table = "MESSAGE_REPORT", name = "REF_CLIENT")
    protected String refClient;

    @Column(table = "MESSAGE_REPORT", name = "CALLBACK_URL")
    protected String callbackUrl;

    @Column(table = "MESSAGE_REPORT", name = "CALLBACK_URL_REPONSE")
    protected String callbackUrlReponse;

    //constructors and getters/setters etc ....

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE_REPORT")
public class MessageReport implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "REPORT_REFERENCE", length = 36)
    private String reportReference = "";

    @Column(name = "STATUS", length = 20)
    private String status = "";

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
    private Date creationDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "SENT_DATE")
    private Date sentDate;

    @Column(name = "SIZE")
    private Integer size;

    @Column(name = "CALLBACK_URL")
    private String callbackUrl;

    @Column(name = "CALLBACK_URL_REPONSE")
    private String callbackUrlReponse;

    @Column(name = "REF_CLIENT")
    private String refClient;

}
```

The problem that I have occurs when implementing a simple update : I've created and am trying to call this method that uses a JPA @Query :

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE #{#entityName} m " +
    "set m.text = :text, " +
    "m.fromField = :from, " +
    "m.refClient = :refClient, " +
    "m.sentDate = :sentDate " +
    "WHERE m.campaign = :campaignId")
    void    updateMessageFromPatchedCampaign(
            @Param(value = "campaignId") Campaign campaign,
            @Param(value = "text") String text,
            @Param(value = "from") String from,
            @Param(value = "refClient") String refClient,
            @Param(value = "sentDate") Date sentDate);
```

(in that case, entityName is mapped to MESSAGE).
What happens is that the subquery supposed to update the REF_CLIENT column (refClient) on the MESSAGE_REPORT table is created by Hibernate by using MESSAGE_ID in the where clause instead of REPORT_REFERENCE, like this :

```
2022-10-31 09:41:03 Failed Query Report SQL=update MESSAGE_REPORT set REF_CLIENT=? where (MESSAGE_ID = 'XXXXX') or (MESSAGE_ID = 'XXXXX') or (MESSAGE_ID = 'XXXXX') or (MESSAGE_ID = 'XXXXX') or (MESSAGE_ID = 'XXXXX'); - [maxime-Inspiron-16-5620]
```

(I've replaced the actual id values with XXXXX)
If I was the one who developed the app, I would have used a OneToOne relationship between MESSAGE and MESSAGE_REPORT and would have put a @JoinColumn with a MessageReport attribute in the Message class, but this is what I'm working with.

How can I make sure that the correct column (REPORT_REFERENCE) is used when Hibernate generates the subquery used to update REF_CLIENT, and not MESSAGE_ID ? I've tried changing the definition of the @SecondaryTable to

```
@SecondaryTable(
        name = "MESSAGE_REPORT",
        pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(
                name = "MESSAGE_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "REPORT_REFERENCE")
```

but then it stops at launch with this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: REPORT_REFERENCE in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(MESSAGE) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

so I am truly unsure on how to go from there. Sure, I could modify the UPDATE query to only update the table MESSAGE and create another method to update MESSAGE_REPORT but I feel like that's suboptimal. Any ideas ? Any help will be greatly appreciated ! Thanks

**Edit :**

Even by using the secondary table that way :

```
@SecondaryTable(
        name = "MESSAGE_REPORT",
        pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(
                name = "REPORT_REFERENCE",
                referencedColumnName = "MESSAGE_ID"))
```

I still get the same issue where the UPDATE query is created with MESSAGE_ID in the WHERE clause.

EDIT : I couldn't find an answer/a solution, so I just implementend two different queries.

Comment: Secondary table references are treated as FKs from the secondary table to the primary one - PrimaryKeyJoinColumn's name is the FK from the second table to the first. So you've got it backwards, it should be MESSAGE_ID is referenced by REPORT_REFERENCE. Update statements can only hit one table at a time, so I don't see why you'd think having two queries over the two separate entities would make any difference to the performance; Your provider will break up this query to statements targeting the relevant table(s) anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I said that having two queries would be suboptimal, I wasn't talking about performance but about the fact that the entities are designed in a way where I shouldn't need to use two queries.

About your first answer, even if I write down the secondary table with the MESSAGE_ID referenced by REPORT_REFERENCE, I still get the same behaviour (The query is created with MESSAGE_ID in the WHERE clause for the update on MESSAGE_REPORT). Any idea about that issue ?

Comment: No clue: looks like a bug, but this should be pretty standard behavior. Check the versions being used, and that you don't have other settings that might conflict that are going unnoticed where you run this and see the problem. Does inserts and updates via persist/merge api work as expected? Are you able to reproduce this in a separate model/project or is it only this one that shows this sort of behavior?